# How do I "speed" rollerblade?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

So apparently, I've been getting some weird controls.

I've found that if I mash the analog stick around in circles, I can pull off even faster rollerblading.  More rollerblading, per rollerblade.

I can't seem to replicate this though.

Is there anyway I can consistently "speed" skate, or skate really fast in Pokemon X&Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a roller blading technique. There is an NPC in Lumiose city who tells you that if you move the analog stick in small circles in the direction of movement, you will use a special technique.

Comment: Wait what, I haven't even reached this Lumiose city yet

Comment: I'm sure you can use the technique before you're actually told about it. You must have accidentally stumbled upon it